# I am trying to change the name of file, but script has giving me errors

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
touch etc/skel/.abc
cat << EOF > etc/skel/.abc
test -f .profile && source .profile

    if [ -f "etc/skel/.runonce" ]
        then
        source etc/skel/.runonce
        mv "etc/skel/.runonce" "etc/skel/.ranonce"
    else
        echo ".runoce doesn't exist"

    fi
```

Comment: @Corion Thanks. I figured it out. Actually I was running .runonce after the other file and in .runonce I was referring to some other directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test `[ -f "etc/skel/.runonce" ]` succeeded, so something did go wrong when you sourced it.
I don't expect you to be removing files in `.runonce`, so I think you did a changedir somewhere. Please check your `cd` commands.
Note:
When the commands only changes files and not set any important variables, you can better run the file (`chmod +x etc/skel/.runonce; etc/skel/.runonce; chmod -x etc/skel/.runonce`).

EDIT:
In the comment OP writes the script under runonce:

I think this is the script that creates the file `.runonce`. I see the redirection `> etc/skel/.runonce`, and that would be weird inside the `.runonce` file.
When the `.runonce` has been created with `cat <<EOF ... EOF` but only has commands inside the file, the commands inside the file will be executed.

EDIT 2:
OP suggested the script

```
if [[ -e /.ssh ]]
then
   cd /ssh
   git init 
else
   mkdir /ssh
   cd  /ssh
   git init
fi # OP did not this fi
cd
```

It is rather confusing having both a directory `/ssh` and `/.ssh`. I would use `/gitrepos`.
When `$HOME` refers to `/` (only run by root), this might be changed into

```
if [[ -d /.ssh ]]
then
   # Always make /gitrepos, ignore errors 
   mkdir /gitrepos 2>/dev/null
   # Alternative: Only mkdir when /gitrepos is not a dir
   # test -d /gitrepos || mkdir /gitrepos
   # Both mkdir's will fail when you have a regular file names /gitrepos
   cd /gitrepos
   git init 
   cd
else
   echo "You have no .ssh setup."
fi
```

Comment: @JosephSible first of all, I am running the actual file than I am running .bash_profile in etc/skel directory.

Comment: Everything else in the script is working. I mean it is sourcing the .runonce file but I am not getting why doesn't mv command is not working.

Comment: See my edit: Are any commands inside `.runonce` being executed?

Comment: Yeah, using `cd` in a sourced script like this can cause all sorts of chaos. When you try to mv `etc/skel/.runonce` after sourcing it, it now refers to something like $HOME/.ssh/etc/skel/.runonce, which *doesn't* exist and you get an error. Lesson: use absolute paths and don't `cd` without understanding the implications.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're executing this from the root directory (or `cd /` at the beginning), you need a `/` before `etc` everywhere.

Comment: That's not consitent with the error output they get